# Place all featured images inside content of all posts Wordpress. Possible?

Tags: wordpress

It is possible to place all featured images (from all posts) attached to posts and place them inside content like way  of ech posts?

- perefcly at top.

Quite the opposite as familiar grabbing the first image of the article and set it as the featured.

If so? How?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom query inside your first post loop and pull all the posts, then inside every post of second loop, that you'l receive, show it's featured image.